# .htaccess SetEnvIfNoCase Host exclude specific subdomain

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, environment-variables

We got a bunch of domains for one vhost.
All domains including any subdomains require a basic auth except we define them as "live". When defining a domain as "live" also all subdomains are `live`.

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Host ^(.*\.)?domain1\.tld$ live
SetEnvIfNoCase Host ^(.*\.)?domain2\.tld$ live

<RequireAny>
    Require valid-user
    Require env live
</RequireAny>
```

Now I want to exclude `dev.domain1.tld` , so that the basic auth is required again.

How do I need to change RegEx in order to exclude `dev.domain1.tld` ?

Comment: `SetEnvIfNoCase Host ^((?!dev\.).*\.)?domain1\.tld$ ` should do the trick

Comment: Yeah that works great! What if I want to exclude another subdomain? Would it be `^((?!dev\.|!test\.).*\.)?domain1\.tld$` then? 

Also, please post your comment as answer so I can accept it. Thanks so much, you saved my day!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do as @AmitVerma suggested in comments and use a *negative lookahead*. Or, you can simply unset the `live` env var when that hostname is requested.

For example:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Host ^([^.]+\.)?domain1\.tld$ live
SetEnvIfNoCase Host ^www\.domain1\.tld$ !live
```

The `!` prefix on the env var in the second directive *unsets* the previously set `live` env var.

Just to note `(.*\.)` would match any number of sub-subdomains, in case that is an issue.

> Would it be `^((?!dev\.|!test\.).*\.)?domain1\.tld$` then?

You should remove the second `!` and you can remove the literal `\.` (literal dot) from the *alternation*. It is the `?!` after the opening parenthesis that defines the *negative lookahead* (ie. the subpattern that should not occur). For example:

```
^((?!dev|test).*\.)?domain1\.tld$
```